# After Update to 8.5.6, "Add" Links Missing From Page but still are in router

Tags: 8, theming, nodes, updating

I recently **manually** updated Drupal to the 8.5.6 version.  I did this by moveing over the files (using command line) according to Drupal.org instructions and running update.php.

I have two issues that I'm guessing are related:

1. My themes no longer toggle from the front end and I can't force them to change by clearing cache, running cron, rebuilding menu or anything else that I can think of.
2. All "add" links are missing ** - "Node/add" is present in the routing file and still works.  However, it is missing from the content page. It also seems that ALL "add" links are missing from the site. To get there, I need to manually type in the path.

I am running out of obvious ideas on how to fix.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**I followed the instructions below:**

[Drupal Page on Running Installation Manually](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-manually)

Below, you can see the commands Drupal tells you to follow:

```
cd /path/to/your/drupal/directory
rm -rf core vendor
rm -f *.* .[a-z]*
wget https://www.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-x.y.z.tar.gz
tar -zxvf drupal-x.y.z.tar.gz
cd drupal-x.y.z
cp -R core vendor /path/to/your/drupal/directory
cp *.* .[a-z]* /path/to/your/drupal/directory
```

Comment: What was the method you used to update Drupal before?

Comment: When you "dragged over" the files did you remove the old versions first? If not, there may be conflicting implementations present.

Comment: This is the first time that I had done an update.  I dragged the folders "core" and "vendor" over using FTP per the instructions and then I made sure that the permissions were set correctly so the web server could access them.

Comment: Alfred, I believe I did according to the instructions.  I also think that I did this twice.  I'm happy to go find the instructions on Drupal and follow them more closely.  I would assume it is my fault but the struggle is figuring out what I messed up!

Comment: Can you check that there is no "core" folder inside the "core" folder? Same for "vendor"?

Comment: I did check that.  There was no such folder in either of the spots. I will update my original post to show the steps that I followed.

Comment: NOt quite sure why there's a deleted answer by @Scoot that was then deleted again. But at least for the add thing, my guess would have been that the local actions block was somehow missing, no idea how that would be related to an update though

Comment: I deleted the answer b/c I had thought it was fixed but was actually looking at an older version of the server pre-update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your feedback.

We ended up wiping the whole server and starting over.  I had done various updates manually by dragging and dropping. We re-installed Drupal and this time around used composer and drush.  That solved the issue. I was not able to ever FINALLY diagnose what happened.